# How to check if date is a current date with using dayjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a problem with checking if my `date` in unix is a current date with using `dayjs` library, I try like below:

```
const date = 1631978008; //today: 2021-09-18
const isToday = dayjs().isSame(date, 'day'); //return false
```

but always return me false when my `date` is a today date, can someone tell me why? it should return true :/

thanks for any help!

Comment: Your timestamp are seconds, not milliseconds - `1631978008` lacks three zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [unix function](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/unix-timestamp) to parse the unix timestamp in seconds before comparing it with the current time.

```js
const date = 1631978008; //today: 2021-09-18
const isToday = dayjs().isSame(dayjs.unix(date), 'day'); 

console.log(isToday);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
```